# Rails: form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, relation

I have one city with many people.

I want to add a select-field in my city form to add people:

```
<%= form_for(@city) do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label city.people.id, "Person" %><br />
  <%= f.select  city.people.id,
         Person.find(:all).collect{|d| [d.person_name,d.id]},
         :prompt => "Please choose" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Rails said: undefinied varialbe city.
I implemented in city has:many and in person belongs_to.

Whats wrong with my code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the instance variable `@city`, don't forget the @ symbol.

Also, `@city.people` is a collection of type Person, so `@city.people.id` does not work.

Comment: I dont understand what do you exactly mean? Should i try @city.person_id?

Comment: The problem is that a city has_many people, right?  So when you do @city.people, you don't get just one result, you get many. This is represented as an array of instances of type Person.